# @selector retrieving same method name from another file

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've got a PCOTouchGameLayer class, which I wanted to make another version of without subclassing. I have duplicated the source files and created a PCOTouchLinkGameLayer. Inside of it I'm calling the line below:

```
id function1 = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(colorButton)];
```

However, it retrieves the colorButton from PCOTouchGameLayer instead.
I've put the declaration of the method inside a category in PCOTouchGameLayer.m:

```
@interface PCOTouchGameLayer ()

-(void)colorButton;

@end
```

But XCode, when using "Jump to definition" function inside PCOTouchLinkGameLayer jumps to PCOTouchGameLayer. So does the compiler.

Not sure how to tackle this problem without renaming the name of the methods. I thought hiding them inside a category would sort out the problem.

Comment: You mean the colorButton method of the wrong class runs when you execute the call func action? If so, just change the target from self to the instance of the class that should run the selector. But I find it even better style to handle it within the class, then forward the message to the class in question. That way, if something goes wrong (ie target deallocated or is nil), it doesn't crash inside the action but within your own class.

Comment: It is easy to get Xcode confused on code indexing ... dont pay too much attention to it. I dont know what you mean by 'the compiler jumps to ...' ! Be more specific about any error or warnings you get. What matters is what happens when you run.

Comment: Oh, and copy-paste can lead to errors :) show the @implementation and @interface statements of `PCOTouchLinkGameLayer`

Comment: `@selector` doesn't reference a particular method -- it only encapsulates the method name in a form that's convenient for the "messaging" mechanism.  If it's going to the "wrong" object that's because you specified the wrong pointer on the call.  And what Xcode does during editing is just based on it's best guess given the available info.

Comment: Thanks everybody! It turned out to be a bug on my side. I made a mistake of assuming that XCode follows to the method within the same source file. Where in fact it follows wherever it feels like. What I meant by "compiler jumping" is that it seemed at the time that it did go out to another source file, although the pointer was correct, but I wasn't able to reproduce it after. My laptop ran down of battery, after restarting XCode was pointing to right methods so I assume I made a mistake when debugging, because of my false assumption. Thanks for all the knowledge.